# latexindent texlive and texstudio

Tags: texlive, texstudio, latexindent

I am using TeXStudio with texlive on Windows 10 computer. I would like TeXStudio to automatically handle my indentation in my tex-files. My question is:
How to install latexindent in texstudio when using  texlive?

Comment: do you have `arara` installed? if so, `arara` ships with a rule for `latexindent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TeXstudio you may add the `latexindent` script  to "User Commands". For this you need to use the dialog "Configure Texstudio.." in menu "Options". Then you need select section "Build". Then, on the right side of the screen at the bottom you need to click "Add" button and enter the name for your new command and the command itself. The result should be something similar to the picture.

[image]

The new command will be available through the menu: "Tools -> User".

Comment: +1 does this run `latexindent` ever time the user compiles...?

Comment: @cmhughes, in TeXstudio you can configure commands for build, for example, for "Default Compiler". And you can add to "compile chain" this command.